# In D&D 5e, can a Human be Reborn as a Lizardfolk?

Tags: dnd-5e, lizardfolk

I have a Lizardfolk character who was originally a human who got sick from a fungi infestation, who went to a Necromancer who murdered them and resurrected them in a Lizardfolk's body. I read the Reborn trait rules and thought this would fall under the "You were magically resurrected but something went wrong." but I also read below that the "Creature Type. You are a Humanoid."

I was unsure if a Lizardfolk character would fall under "humanoid".

Lemme know if you have any ideas or if I misinterpreted something.

Comment: Are you saying that you are using the Reborn lineage, but flavored as Lizardfolk, or that you are using the Lizardfolk race?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Lizardfolk are humanoids.

This can be seen both in [lizardfolk NPC statblocks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16946-lizardfolk),

> Medium Humanoid (Lizardfolk)

and the [lizardfolk playable race description](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/1026396-lizardfolk):

> ##### Creature Type
>
> You are a Humanoid.

That said, the Reborn origin doesn’t really have hard rules about backstory anyway, so you can work with your DM to do whatever the two of you want with your character’s origins.

Comment: This answer could be improved by referring to the monster manual's definition of "humanoid" to show that it is a wide variety of creatures, not just humans.